# can't dynamically add activeadmin gem to autoload_paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I am using heroku for my main app, but now i have separated it  to main_app and admin_app (memory issues).

So i have 2 apps running on the same git repo with no problems.

main_app uses subdomain admin. to resolve admin_app

now i want to save some memory without loading active admin.

i use a group in gemfile

```
group :admin_app do
  gem 'activeadmin', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin'
end
```

and in application.rb  when admin_app loaded

```
 Bundler.require(*Rails.groups,:admin_app)
```

Now, i have the admin folder which is located on app/admin 
gets auto loaded so i have to ignore it or else i get an exception (no active_admin gem on main_app)

i solved it by a simple if statement

```
if Rails.application.secrets.admin_app

ActiveAdmin.register ForumTopic ....

end
```

i am looking for a better fix for this problem .

i tried moving admin folder to lib or outside the app folder and then add it to

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('admin')
```

but i just don't see it get loaded when using

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
```

i whould like to hear your ideas, thank's

Comment: Did you try making an environment for the admin app? You might be able to update the autoloader from there, as I believe modifying it is blocked once some base files have been loaded

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find the reason autoload_paths didn't include my files.

I add active_admin files to 'lib' folder and then conditionally required them when

drawing the active_admin routes.